# 21.04 - Strange selection box dragging issue

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've recently installed 21.04 and I seem to be having an issue when I try to drag a selection box. Here's a GIF to illustrate the problem:

[image]

I have two monitors and the issue does not occur if I set them to duplicate or just use the one monitor.
One of my monitors is 1080p whilst the other is 2560x1440 and I'm wondering if it's some compatibility issue?
I can also see a tiny bit of the selection box on the right-side of my 2nd monitor (which is actually to the left of my primary monitor), not sure if it's relevant.

EDIT: I've just noticed that the issue only affects the right-most monitor. If I swap the monitors around (in display settings, not physically :D), then the issue affects the now right-most monitor.

I'm also seeing some slowness when I try to drag a window:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Information as requested:
wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF

printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"

Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Session: ubuntu

ps -e | grep tty
2046 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-x-session
2048 tty2     00:09:35 Xorg
2216 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
0: +*DP-0 2560/597x1440/336+1920+0  DP-0
1: +HDMI-0 1920/531x1080/298+0+0  HDMI-0

Comment: JUST A CONFIRMATION:  This have happened to me (and, believe me or not - but right now) on my Debian computer. This is `probably` not *only* in Ubuntu. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Which window manager ( `wmctrl -m`), which desktop (`printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"`), which display server (`ps -e | grep tty` or `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`), which monitors (`xrandr --listmonitors`)?

Comment: I acutally decided to just turn off 'Desktop Icons ning' in Gnome Tweaks > Extensions, seeing as I have no desktop icons anyway. This fixed the selection box issue.

I still get the issue when I try move Brave. It also loads up very slowly the first time round.